# add elements in 2nd dropdown list depending upon the element selected in 1st dropdown using jquery and php

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to populate Cities as per the State selected by user in dropdown lists.

I've a function in jquery defined as:

```
function onchange1(dropdownmenu,field_name,id)
{
  alert(field_name);

  $.post(
  'wppb.city.php', 
  { field_name: id},
  function(data) {
    alert(data);
    $('#'+dropdownname).html(data);

    alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
  });   

  alert($('#'+dropdownname).html());
}
```

and I'm trying to get values from the location where I've called this function.
I've called this function in html tags as:

```
<select name="state" id=state onChange="onchange1(city,state,this.value);">
```

where city is the name of my 2nd dropdownmenu, state is the field_name and this.value is the id.

But when this function is being called and when alerted it's showing [objectHTMLSelectElement].

How to retrieve values from HTML and use it in jquery function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe what you want is

```
$('#'+field_name.id).val()
```

You might also want to look into serializeObject , a good post is this [Convert form data to JavaScript object with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1184624/convert-form-data-to-js-object-with-jquery)

Comment: thanks, i referred the link you gave and i found the solution :)